# Extend the cells in a view in Lotus Notes 7

Tags: view, cell, lotus-notes, rows

I have a view which contains 5 columns. Each column has a value of a field.

For example if a value from a text field is to big, let say: " sadereara meareareareea erarearea emeammera" in the view' column it appears only : "saderera ". It appears only in he specified length of the column.

Is there any possibility to expand / extand the cell / the row to see all the text, not just a part of it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In View properties on the Style tab (3rd tab) you can set height of Rows to e.g. 9 and then mark the Shrink rows to content option.

[image]

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, very mmuch, dear Per Henrik!